# EF5 always sets id to 0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm adding objects to a database where the id isn't auto-autogenerated in the database due to me wanting to specify the id myself (It's stupid I know, just play along ^^)

So I'm using **Entity Framework 5** to insert the data into the database, however, eventhou I set the id before saving it, when I look in the database it's always zero. Why is this and how do I fix it?

The code is like this:

```
    public Profile Add()
    {
        Profile item = new Profile()
        {
            id = 1,
            name = "Bob"
        };

        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return item;
    }
```

**EDIT**

I tried with db.Profiles.Add(item). Same problem

Comment: You need to add the entity to the context `db.Table.Add(item)`

Comment: Using the change tracker API as per chapter 5 in programming entity framework dbContext suggests it should be enough to change the state. I quote : "The state property also exposes a public setter, meaning you can assign a state to an entity. Setting a state is useful when you are working with disconnected graphs of entities typically in N-tier scenario's. Bottom line explicitly adding or setting the state are basically the same thing. His code should work. And an insert is definitely generated. Better check the sql. Is id mapped at all ?

Comment: Is this code first ? How is the mapping of id ?

Comment: Identity column with seed = 0 ?

Comment: It is possible that you modified your database after pulling in the model, in this case the sql will not include a value for id.I have the feeling that your database and model are out of sync

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: I'm using database first.
Before adding to the database I disable `auto_increment` on the id to be able to give it a custom id. That's the only difference, whould that be enough? Because the name is the same and it's still primary key. All the other values gets inserted as the should

Comment: If you want to give it a custom ID don't enable autoincrement

Comment: @JAT: sorry I meant that I disable it ^^

Comment: So you run the code, then check the database and the id is zero? Why are you not receiving a  `Cannot insert duplicate key ` error? show your connection string

Comment: @JAT I do get the `Cannot insert duplicate key` due to all the keys being set to zero

Comment: In your edmx designer, right click id column, select properties, in  StoreGeneratedPattern property, select none, does that work?

Comment: Disable auto_increment in SQL and update edmx (right click edmx designer, update model from database)

Comment: @JAT I could kiss you, setting the  StoreGeneratedPattern to none fixed it ^^

Comment: OK, I'm going to answer it, please mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.- In your edmx designer, right click id column, select properties

2.- In StoreGeneratedPattern select `None`

[image]

As PhilipStuyck said, your model was out of sync with your database, whenever you change the database you must update the model (Right click empty space in edmx designer select `Update model from database`).

Answer (score 1):

Check that your database and your model are actually the same.
If you created your model from an existing database and then changed the database then your model is out of sync. This can also happen with code first of course.
Bottom line is that your sql will do an insert without a value for id, because EF thinks your id is going to come from the database. If you inspect the sql you will see an insert without id being provided followed with a select to get the value for id.
Conclusion is that your model and db are not the same.

Right click the designer and do update model from database.
You might have to remove your id column, or the table to begin with, EF will correct everything

Comment: Is there a way to update the EF model throu code. This is because I as mentioned in one of my other comments update the database before adding? And if possible I whould like to keep that. So if it is possible to call a model update from a method that whould be great

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the table that you are adding it to.

so for you that would be db.NAMEOFTABLE.add(item)

normally you don't have to change the entity state to added. 
Atleast I didn't have to do that in my solution.

Comment: page 80 programming entity framework dbContext : "Calling DbSet.add and setting the state to added both achieve exactly the same thing.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck - Not true, When you use dbContext.SomeEntitySet.Add(entityInstance); the status for this and all its related entities/collections is set to added, while dbContext.Entry(entityInstance).State = EntityState.Added; adds also all the related entities/collections to the context but leaves them as unmodified. So if the entity that you are trying to create has a related entity (and it's value its not null), when you use Add it will create a new object for that child entity, while with the other way it won't

Comment: No you are wrong. When an element is set to the added state EF is going to look into the navigation properties of the other entities that are not being change tracked and put those to added as well. page 73.

Comment: Perhaps, but then again, there are no navigation properties in Profile. How does this help the OP ? Julia Lerman is an authority in this matter, I am not claiming to be. I would be really suprised if my info is wrong. Are your navigation properties virtual ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck, I have worked with EF for around 3 years, I am happy with my own conclusions. Good luck with your book, I expect she was referring to childless entities, either way I can assure you I am correct and on this occasion your info is incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68604/discussion-between-philip-stuyck-and-benjaminpaul).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the entity to the DbSet that represents your profiles table... something like this...

```
public Profile Add()
    {
        Profile item = db.Profiles.Create();
        item.Name = "Bob";

        db.Profiles.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return item;
    }
```

I prefer using the Create method however it makes no difference.

Comment: page 80 programming entity framework dbContext : "Calling DbSet.add and setting the state to added both achieve exactly the same thing.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck - Not true, When you use dbContext.SomeEntitySet.Add(entityInstance); the status for this and all its related entities/collections is set to added, while dbContext.Entry(entityInstance).State = EntityState.Added; adds also all the related entities/collections to the context but leaves them as unmodified. So if the entity that you are trying to create has a related entity (and it's value its not null), when you use Add it will create a new object for that child entity, while with the other way it won't.

Comment: No you are wrong. When an element is set to the added state EF is going to look into the navigation properties of the other entities that are not being change tracked and put those to added as well. page 73.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul, I verified this by now in the code and the book is correct. As expected. Using the change tracker is the same as adding to a dbset. Mistakes can happen in books, but not an entire chapter wide. I don't know your code of course, perhaps the navigation properties need to be virtual, mine are. If They are not, then EF cannot know I expect and an explicit call to detect changes would be needed i guess

Answer (score 0):

By default `Id` property is treated as Primary Key and as Identity by Entity Framework. So it just ignores property value, while generating sql for insert command. You should specify metadata explicitly: add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` attribute or use method `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption` from FluentApi.

Comment: Oh, missed that possibility. Answer by @Philip Stuyck should be the right one in that case.